# Using multiple booleans in an if statement to decide which file to write to

Tags: python, if-statement, io, boolean

I'm trying to catch 4570 close encounters between planets, and output the data into certain files, depending on which two planets had the close encounters. I have 5 planets in total, and each planet has a close encounter ONLY with the planet(s) adjacent to it, leaving the possibility of 4 encounters.

```
data1 = open('data1.txt', 'a+')
data2 = open('data2.txt', 'a+')
data3 = open('data3.txt', 'a+')
data4 = open('data4.txt', 'a+')

for i in range(0,100000): #range this big since close encounters don't happen every iteration      
    def P_dist(p1, p2):
        #function calculating distances between planets


    init_SMA = [sim.particles[1].a,sim.particles[2].a,sim.particles[3].a,sim.particles[4].a,sim.particles[5].a]

    try:
        sim.integrate(10e+9*2*np.pi)
    except rebound.Encounter as error:
        print(error)

    for j in range(len(init_SMA)-1):
        distance = P_dist(j, j+1)
        if distance <= .01:
            count+=1
            if count > 4570:
                break
            elif(init_SMA[j] == init_SMA[0] and init_SMA[j+1] == init_SMA[1])
                #write stuff to data1
            elif(init_SMA[j] == init_SMA[1] and init_SMA[j+1] == init_SMA[2])
                #write stuff to data2
            elif(init_SMA[j] == init_SMA[2] and init_SMA[j+1] == init_SMA[3])
                #write stuff to data3
            elif(init_SMA[j] == init_SMA[3] and init_SMA[j+1] == init_SMA[4])
                #write stuff to data4

#close files
```

Everyone, I apologize. I left out lots of the code that shows the creation of the planetary system. The main for loop is responsible for creating a planetary system, catching a close encounter, writing it to the files, and repeating until 4570 close encounters have occurred.

Comment: seems like you mix SMA and sma (are these different?) then, you calc distance j to j+1, but that doesn't cover every case (you have 5 x 4 cases = 20, not just 4)

Comment: why do you break the loop if count if greater than 4570? that loop only has four 5 iterations

Comment: @MrE, in my case, close encounters only happen between adjacent planets. Only 4 cases are possible. However,+1 for catching the sma/SMA thing.

Comment: @djk47463 a bit confused of what you're asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't ideal to keep four different files open in a running script. What's more, you haven't opened those files using Python's convenient `with` context manager, which takes care of cleanly closing opened files among other things. You're also performing open operations every loop iteration - files usually should be opened and closed once as there is a lot of consequential I/O overhead.

As for a cleaner approach, I would conditionally accumulate items/lines in Python data storage objects, then just do a one-off open and write at the end of the script. That way, if something goes awry during the main logic, you don't have files that have been partially written to.

This would be something along the lines of:

```
create 4 empty lists

for loop
    logic to conditionally append lines to be written to the text files to those lists

with open('data1.txt', 'a+') as f:
    write contents of list1 to f
... copy paste for remaining 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably put the four data files in a list, so you can just do:

```
filesArray = [data1,data2,data3,data4]
#insider your for loop:
if(count > 4750):
    break
if(distance <= 0.01):
    count += 1
    filesArray[j].write(data)#for whatever your data is
else:
    break
```

It would be even better to do

```
fileNamesArray = ["data1.txt", "data2.txt", "data3.txt", "data4.txt"]
#inside your for loop:
if(count > 4750):
    break
if(distance <= 0.01):
    count += 1
    with open(fileNamesArray[j], "a") as dataFile:
        dataFile.write(data)#for whatever your data is
```

This helps avoid data corruption in case your program crashes for another reason

This also avoids storing every result you get into a list in memory, which I'd guess could be expensive for complex simulations

It does bind your performance to disk speed though, so I guess it's a tradeoff

Comment: This will open/close the file for every write -- very slow for 4750 operations.

Comment: Was just going to comment the above. This code is not ideal either.

Comment: I didn't want to assume the question asker has buckets of ram lying around, and I didn't know the size of each "data" block they were writing - each planet could represent a couple of megabytes of data, and then you save 4750 of them to a set of lists? you'll be using swap memory fast, and then its slow either way